# Updating Multiple Records using Eloquent (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query that is working but I'm wondering what the Eloquent ORM equivalent would be?

```
       DB::table('exercises')->whereIn('id', $ids)->update($request->all());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eloquent equivalent is almost the same:

```
Exercise::whereIn('id', $ids)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: sorry for comment here, how can i check first in multiple rows ?

Comment: what do you mean by first?

Answer (score 4):

Here, 
$ids = [1,2,3];

```
DB::table('users')
   ->whereIn('id', $ids)
   ->update(array('active' => true));
```

By using the above query we can update multiple rows same time.

Answer (score -1):

**A current syntax using DB**

`DB::table('users')

->whereIn('id', $ids)

->update(['active' => true]);`